# Can I change the time delay length for when I require a password in the App Store (iOS 8)?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

I currently have iOS 8.1 running on an iPhone 6 Plus.

I just switched back to Apple after being on Android for a year. On the Google Play store, after making a purchase & entering my password, I could choose the amount of time that could pass before I'd require that password again. I can't remember if this is possible on the Apple App Store, but I haven't been able to find that setting if it is.

Does anyone know if/how this is possible on iOS?

***Note:*** I am jailbroken if there's a tweak out there for this. I've found a Cydia app that will automatically enter my password, but that's not what I'm looking for. I just want to increase the delay before I need to enter my password again.

Comment: The best you can do is set up Touch ID so you can use a fingerprint instead of typing in your password. There is no way to alter the timing of it requiring your password again (which I believe is 15 minutes) - at least, without jailbreaking. I don't know if there is anything on the jailbroken side that can change it.

Comment: +1  fingerprint was the best thing Apple have added to the iPhone range.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)

I've already decided against using touch ID, simply because it forces me to password protect my lock screen in order to use the feature anywhere else. It's a great feature and I loved having the ability to use it in the App Store while I had it on. I've just never liked locking down my lock screen and, IMHO, that requirement is an odd choice. 

I'd hoped that the print scanner was a feature that improved convenience AND security, but it seems that Apple sees it/designed it strictly as a security feature.

Comment: I'm not sure of delay for iTunes store but there is delay available for lock screen (jailbreak tweak)